# Declaring a value and executing it cannot be used in the same stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures, declare

I'm stuck on an error in MS SQL Server.
I'm making a stored procedure in which I declare a value, I set it as a select statement, and execute it. Then I want to use it later in the same stored procedure, but It still sees it as a select statement, and not as a result of the statement.

Declaring:

```
Declare @functie varchar(255);
Set @functie = 'Select Functie From Medewerker m, Logins l where m.mdwnr = l.mdwnr And gebruikersnaam = ''' + @GebruikersNaam + '''' 
EXECUTE(@functie)
Print @functie
```

Comparing it afterwards (does not work):

```
If '+ @functie + ' = ''Administrator''
Print ' + @functie + '
```

The prints are used to debug, and are not necessary.

How can I fix this?

Comment: That `if` statement is simply wrong - `''Administrator''` isn't a valid string, and the first string is a hard-coded `'+ @functie + '`. Perhaps you should fix the typos and try code that actually compiles? Did you mean to use `if @functie = 'Administrator'` ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need dynamic sql here at all. Here is your query setting the value of the variable.

```
Declare @functie varchar(255);
Select @functie = Functie 
From Medewerker m
join Logins l on m.mdwnr = l.mdwnr 
    And gebruikersnaam = @GebruikersNaam
```

Also, you should get in the habit of using ANSI-92 style joins instead of the out of data comma separated list of tables. The "newer" join syntax is nearly 30 years old now.

- [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from EXEC only to the table, then you can parse that info depending on your requirements. Here is possible example of that:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(255) = 'Select ''test''' 
DECLARE @result TABLE (functie nvarchar(100))
DECLARE @functie nvarchar(100)
INSERT INTO @result EXECUTE(@sql)
SET @functie = (SELECT TOP(1) functie FROM @result)
PRINT(@functie)
```

However previous comment is perfect, you don't need Dynamic SQL for this operation, and parametrized query may save your ass in case of SQL Injection (which looks possible in your code).

Answer (score 0):

The prior answer my resolve your issue - I wanted to note also that your comparison code is incorrect - using two single quote characters in a row resolves to one single quote character (rather than being treated as a text delimiter).

If you will be getting single quotes back as part of your result, then that code should look like:

`If '' + @functie + '' = '''Administrator'''
Print @functie`